# Take out part of the string from part of vector in R

Tags: r

I have this question tidying up the data. I have a vector called "opponent" like this:

```
vs. wakeforest
Utah
vs. [9] Los Angelas
Seattle
vs. [11] UNC
at [19] North Carolina
```

I only want the opponent name, that is:

```
wakeforest
Utah
Los Angelas
Seattle
UNC
North Carolina
```

How should I clean it up? Thanks a lot!

Comment: welcome to SO. You should always post [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code - not just ask for some code for free. Maybe someone will answer but it can happen that you will receive downvote.

Comment: Yup got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can match characters until the `.` or `]` followed by one or more space (`\\s+`) and replace it with `''`.

```
sub('^.*(\\.|\\])\\s+', '', opponent)
#[1] "wakeforest"     "Utah"           "Los Angelas"    "Seattle"       
#[5] "UNC"            "North Carolina"
```

#### data

```
opponent <- c('vs. wakeforest', 'Utah',
'vs. [9] Los Angelas', 'Seattle',
'vs. [11] UNC','at [19] North Carolina')
```